# Metro JS/HTML5 app and Table Storage

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, azure-storage, azure-table-storage, winjs

I'm trying to find out if it is possible to create a Metro style app on Win 8 using JS/HTML5 that stores its data in an Windows Azure table storage.

Couldn't find any sample of that. The only thing I saw is to have push notifications in my Metro style app but not storing data on a table storage.

Is it possible? and where can I find a sample of that?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible.  Check out the [Windows Azure Toolkit for Windows 8 Consumer Prv](http://watwindows8.codeplex.com/releases/view/84166). There is a Windows 8 cloud app in there:

*Immediately, out of the box, the client and server projects integrate to enable push notifications with the Windows Push Notification Service (WNS). In addition, the Windows Azure project demonstrates how to use the Windows Push Notifications Recipe **and how to leverage Windows Azure blob and table storage.***

There are also tons of [Azure samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/).

Comment: Thank you both!

I created a WCF service and hosted it in Windows Azure. Then created a Metro style app using JS/HTML5 and called the WCF service to store and retrieve data.

Is that the right way to done that?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you still need two main things to run Windows Azure Application on Windows 8:

1. [Windows Azure Toolkit for Windows 8](http://watwindows8.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Creating%20a%20New%20Windows%208%20Cloud%20Application&referringTitle=Documentation)
2. [Windows Azure SDK 1.6](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/downloads/) (Latest available)

Once you have that you can still use Azure SDK 1.6 to connect to Windows Azure Table Storage and once you have data you can render using JQuery/JS and or any other UI specific language.